# blocking when run normally, but not during unit tests (StoreAsync)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, .net-4.5

I have an issue here where during unit tests, the StoreAsync() method returns. When run without debugging, it seems to never return even though it is an async method.

What gives?

```
   DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(_client.OutputStream);
   writer.WriteBytes(payload);
   await writer.StoreAsync(); // <--- returns only during unit test
   writer.DetachStream();
```

Comment: One thing's not clear: your problem is the unit test not failing when it should or...?

Comment: Basically I'm saying.. Why is it not failing in the unit test but failing when run normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS 11 Beta, then make sure your unit test is declared as `async Task`.

If you're using VS 11 Dev Preview, then use the [Async Unit Tests project](http://asyncunittests.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex.

I have more information on async unit tests on my blog ([part 1](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html), [part 2](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html)). In summary:

1. When `await` needs to (asynchronously) wait, it schedules a continuation and returns to its caller.
2. MSTest sees the test method return, does not see any exceptions, and marks it as "passed".
3. Later on, the `StoreAsync` will complete and the rest of the method will run (on a thread pool thread, not within the context of that unit test).

VS 11 Beta adds first-class support for `async Task` unit test methods. So the second step above is different: MSTest sees the test method return but knows not to consider it complete until the `Task` completes.

The Async Unit Tests project takes a different approach: it applies an async context for every unit test method in an `[AsyncTestClass]`. This async context waits for all asynchronous operations to complete (including `async void` methods) before completing the unit test.

Comment: hi Stephen, thanks for your reply, the issue here is that when run as a unit test, the StoreAsync operation returns and is able to detach from stream; when run normally, it doesn't. On the receiving end is actually your PacketProtocol handling the TCP message =)

Comment: I see. I've only seen deadlocks like this twice: one is [due to a bug in ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627329/using-an-async-action-to-run-synchronous-code/9635844#9635844) and the other is [when an async method is attempting to synchronize back to a thread that is doing a blocking wait on the returned task](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/269172a3-adb9-4b5e-9ac1-8b67ff920177). Neither of these *seem* to be the case here, but could you try changing `await writer.StoreAsync()` to `await writer.StoreAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`?