# Multithreaded loop with rabbitMQ consumer and WebApi call - WebApi response never returned

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, threadpool, dotnet-httpclient

I've got a multithreaded Windows service which is consuming messages off a Rabbit queue and sending emails based on the content of the messages.

When the rabbit client is initialized at startup, it limits the Threadpool threads with a Min and Max value.

For each message taken off the queue the service is sending an HTTP request to a web api service using `HttpClient` `GetAsync` method to retrieve email address.

The problem is that the request goes off to the data service, but the response never comes back. The windows service keeps consuming messages off the queue and hangs after a while (probably runs of of free threads) - it's waiting for any of the calls to web api to complete which they never do.

I was able to resolve the problem using a `Semaphore` class for the Rabbit loop rather than trying to limit the Threadpool directly, however, I'd like to know why the service got into this state in the first place. Is that to do with the `GetAsync` call? Is it perhaps freeing up the thread for the duration of the request, so that the main loop can steal it for a next request?

Any ideas?

The original loop:

```
while (!_stopped)
            {
                if (_paused) continue;

                try
                {
                    using (var messageBusReceiver = _rabbitQueueClient.ConfigureMessageBusReceiver())
                    {
                        using (_consumer = messageBusReceiver.Listen<PublishableItem>())
                        {
                            while (!_stopped)
                            {
                                 if (_paused) continue;

                                _consumer.Consume(callback, consumeSynchronously: false);

                                _communicationErrorCount = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The `Consume` method is eventually doing this:

```
_threadPoolProvider.QueueUserWorkItem(o => 
            consumeMessage(callback, eventArgs, o), message);
```

The callback begins with the following lines - the null checking line is never reached:

```
var foo = _fooService.GetFoo(messageInfo.FooId);

            if (foo == null)
            {
                throw new FooNotFoundException(
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Foo was not found for FooId of {0}", messageInfo.FooId));
            }
```

The client method:

```
public Foo GetFoo(Guid id)
{

            var path = getPathWithQueryStringAndDebug("getfoo", "id", id.ToString());

            var response = _client.GetAsync(path).Result;

            return processResponse<FooDto>(response);
}
```

Comment: I believe this is one of the FAQs in the async area. Stephen Cleary has a blog entry on the exact same topic. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Badri- thanks for that. I'm not completely convinced that the case in the article is the same thing as there the blocking call is one level up. Here it's the inner most method that actually blocks. But I do get the point that it should not be blocking in the first place probably. Do you know of examples without `async/await` on this topic, I'm on .NET 4.0

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I some how came to a conclusion that a Task is returned. Also, now I see that this is a Windows service.

Comment: I've had some success using this wrapper method to do sync calls on .net 4.0 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14607162/6819