# Synchronous Concurrent HttpClient Usage

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, c#-5.0, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use HttpClient synchronously but when I make many concurrent requests it stops working. I wrote two tests, one for asynchronous usage and one for synchronous usage. `TestMethod` always returns response after 4 seconds. Asynchronous test works fine. Almost all requests are timed out in synchronous test, only ~20 last requests are successful. I tried both using a single `HttpClient` for requests and creating new `HttpClient` instance for each new requests. No difference. Maybe it has something to do with [this deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

I am using VS2013 with .NET Framework 4.5.1 targeting Framework 4.5. I get HttpClient via NuGet: `<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.15" targetFramework="net45" />`

I don't want to use `HttpClient` asynchronously just yet because it means that I have to rewrite my whole app. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

```
// all 800 requests complete successfully
[Test]
public async void Asyncmethod()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 800).Select(x => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var swx = new Stopwatch();
            swx.Start();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:7002/TestMethod").ConfigureAwait(false);
            swx.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(x + " " + response + " in " + swx.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x + " Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    })).ToArray();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

// almost all of 800 requests time out
[Test]
public void Syncmethod()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    var client = new HttpClient();

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 800).Select(x => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var swx = new Stopwatch();
            swx.Start();
            var response = client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:7002/TestMethod");
            if (response.Wait(15000))
            {
                swx.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(x + " " + response.Result + " in " + swx.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
            }
            else
            {
                swx.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(x + " timed out.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x + " Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    })).ToArray();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
        task.Wait(60000);

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I do recommend that you use `await` for `HttpClient` instead of `Wait`. If you truly want synchronous requests, consider using `WebClient` which supports synchronous methods.

That said, I believe the reason you're seeing that behavior is due to `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`, which will throttle the number of requests to a given server. If you want to have large numbers of concurrent requests to the same server (synchronous *or* asynchronous), then you'll need to increase that limit (it is 2 by default for UI applications).

Comment: `await` - after all the question is tagged **C#-5.0**

Comment: The problem is, if there is no timeout, none of the requests is completed. I get around 20 completed requests only after 780 are canceled due to timeout.

Comment: Using await in not an option, I'll have to rewrite everything else too. Yes, `WebClient` works perfectly. But I still don't understand why `HttpClient` hangs.

Comment: The `DefaultConnectionLimit` is a VERY good reason to hang. The default is 2 which means that getting even 20 completed requests is not bad. Just increase the limit

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's seems like deadlock.

This code works perfect

```
public static void Syncmethod()
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 800).Select(x => Task.Run(() =>
        {

            var swx = new Stopwatch();
            swx.Start();
            var result =
            client.GetStringAsync("http://yandex.ru").ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                try
                {
                    swx.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(x + " " + task.Result + " in " + swx.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
                    return task.Result;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    swx.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(x + " Exception: " + e.Message);
                    throw e;
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        })).ToArray();

        foreach (var task in tasks)
            task.Wait(60000);

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

I guess you need additional logic to handle timeout. May be one more task that completes in 15 sec, for example.

Look to this post [HttpClient.GetAsync(...) never returns when using await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async/10351400#10351400)

And as described above you may hang your async example by simple change

```
var response = client.GetStringAsync("http://yandex.ru").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

When you write async code never ever use **block execution and await result.**

Comment: First of all, in your example the task will be completed before the request is completed if request is long enough. Second, how would I write a function that returns something from response using `ContinueWith`?

Comment: Updated. But you have to rewrite you code to use Task<string> without waiting.