# Load an image from web with new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, webrequest, system.net

I am trying to load an image from a webserver into a pictureBox. To not block the Form untill the picture is loaded i start a new Thread which works on the LoadPicture()-function till all work is done.

Everything will be started on a MouseHover-Event so it can be triggered multiple times in a short period as the default WindowsHoverTime is 180ms and can't be changed (i searched a lot on that). 
This is the function:

```
public void LoadPicture(string url)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Timeout = 3500;
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
        {
            int ContentLength;
            if (int.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out ContentLength))
            {
                string ContentType = resp.Headers.Get("Content-Type");
                if (ContentLength < 1048576 && ContentType == "image/png")
                {
                    this.pictureBox1.Load(url);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.pictureBox1.Image = mainprogram.Properties.Resources.sample;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { this.pictureBox1.Image = mainprogram.Properties.Resources.sample; }
}
```

If the url contains a png-file which is smaller than 1MB it should be loaded into pictureBox1, if not, then a deafult image from resources is loaded.

Thread and calling:

```
namespace mainprogram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread threadworker;
        .
        .
        .
        private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (threadworker.IsAlive == false)
            {
                threadworker = new Thread(() => LoadPicture(url));
                threadworker.Start();
            }
        }
```

**Now the problem:** The thread will fail almost all the time. Catch{} will be executed 9/10 times. Mostly crash at WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse(). If i use the function within the same thread (without starting a new one) it will load just fine, but the GUI will stop responding for like 3seconds untill the picture is loaded.

Edit: It DOES work sometimes, so i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: You should use async with `HttpClient` instead of threading.

Comment: nothing as i use try&catch, it will just fail and trigger the catch{} phrase

Comment: @SLaks Can you give a brief example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a lot of research and trouble i got it working.
First i have to thank SLaks for his comment. I used async/await + GetResponseAsync and it was working flawless:

```
public async void LoadPicture(string url)
{
    bool worker = await GetURLContentsAsync(url);
}

private async Task<bool> GetURLContentsAsync(string url)
{
    var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);             
    using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        .
        .
        .
```

Unfortunately GetResponseAsync is only aviable in .NET Framework 4.5 so i tried a different approach with BeginGetResponse from here:
https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=583
But it was either blocking the UI-thread (not asynchronous) or failed to load the picture 3/4 times (same image).

So i ended up using threads again:

```
private void LoadPicture(string url)
{
    threadworker = new Thread(() => pictureBox1.Image = getImgFromUrl(url));
    threadworker.Start();
} 

public Bitmap getImgFromUrl(string url)
{
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        try
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(response.GetResponseStream());
            .
            .
            .
```

As you can see it is almost the same code as in the question-post, i figured out that threadworker.IsAlive was the culprit and pictureBox1.Load() takes a lot longer than writing the stream into a temporary BitMap-file and loading it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

### Using `async`

To exemplify SLaks excellent comment, here is a walktrough on MSDN how to use async/await for the web http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx#BKMK_ConvertGtBtArr

Also lots of explanation on the workings and benefits of async/await on [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10351400/642532).

### Using .NET 4.0

There is also an asyncronous version of `GetResponse` available for .NET 4.0 (and lower) called `BeginGetResponse`. It's documented on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=vs.100).aspx but the example on that page is horrible because it blocks using events. What you want instead is having your callback called in the UI thread. `async`/`await` do so automatically. With callbacks you might have to defer the callback to the UI syncContext manually.

### Remarks

Anyway, all of this is only helpful if your actual problem is an access violation because you try to draw your requested image in a non UI thread and/or blocking the UI. If instead `GetResponse` throws an exception because of DNS problems, error 403/404, timeouts or similar you should instead invest in finding out why.

Comment: Unfortunately `HttpClient` is aviable only in .NET 4.5. I trimmed down my application to work with 4.0 because quite a few users would't want to install the new .NET Framework. Is there a solution without the need of 4.5?