# Why can my WebApi client make only a single GET request?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I wrote a simple client for my web service with Web Api as explained in this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

The first request (GET a table) is executed successfully. That is, table data is fetched from the web service and bound to *TableContent* object.

But the program is totally blocked before executing the second request (GET table list); nothing happens, not even an error message!

If I comment out the code section related with the first request (GET a table) the second request (GET table list) is executed successfully.

What happens here? Why can this client execute only a single GET request?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56510/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    // GET a table from web service
    response = await client.GetAsync("api/table/GetMatrixTable");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var tblcont = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TableContent>();
        // do things ...
    }

    // GET a table list from web service
    response = await client.GetAsync("api/table/GetTableList");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var TblContList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<TableContent>>();
        // do things ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock but I don't see exactly what the cause would be. What type of application is this client? How is the method containing your code sample called?

Comment: This cliend is a console application (.NET 4.5) as explained in this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client As shown in the tutorial, the statement "RunAsync().Wait()" in Main() calls "static async Task RunAsync()", which envelopes the using{} block displayed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the following SO question and its accepted answer (maybe not *directly* relevant but still useful in its own right):

- [HttpClient.GetAsync(...) never returns when using await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)

it might help if you replace your calls to `GetAsync()` as follows:

```
response = await client.GetAsync("api/table/GetMatrixTable",
                 HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
. . .
response = await client.GetAsync("api/table/GetTableList",
                 HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I'm not able to test that so I can't take all the credit if that works.

Comment: Thanks djikay, @tuncalik should really have marked this as the answer.