# Async Method Doesn't Return

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have the following Action method that uses `Scanner` class which uses some webservice to get some data. When I use breakpoint inside `GetSuggestions` method, I can see the result. However, this data is never returned to my Action method. Instead when I check the value of `model` inside `Index()`, it is,

```
Id = 1, Status = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async) question but It did not helped me.

**Controller Action Method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var plane = new Scanner();
    var model = plane.GetSuggestions("ISTANBUL");

    return View(model);
}
```

**GetSuggestions Method :**

```
public async Task<List<PlaceDto>> GetSuggestions(string key)
{
    string url = String.Format("URL GOES HERE", key, API_KEY);

    string data = await RequestProvider.Get(url);

    return JObject.Parse(data).SelectToken("Places").ToObject<List<PlaceDto>>();
}
```

**RequestProvider Method :**

```
public static async Task<string> Get(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 1**

I also tried wrapping the Action method with task and waiting on `GetSuggestions` method but I receive exception on `client.GetStringAsync(url)`

**Exception When I use Task on Action Method**

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Web
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
       at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__1(Object s)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException:
```

---

**Edit 2**

I removed the await keyword from `await client.GetStringAsync(url);` and code works. However, I think this will run synchronously not async. Following is the updated Get method,

```
public static async Task<string> Get(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Return type of `GetSuggestions` is `Task` and you have to call `.Result` to get the `List<PlaceDto>` you need.

Comment: What's the inner exception stack trace?

Comment: @MarcelN. Inner exception is null.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi: You need to change the action signature to `public async Task<ActionResult> Index()` too, in addition to Jason's answer. Not sure if you did that already.

Comment: @MarcelN. Thanks but I have tried that. See my 1. and 2. edits.

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts to your problem.

The first is the deadlock. You need to replace any `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result` calls with `await`. I explain this deadlock scenario more fully [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in the answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10351400/263693).

The second is the exception. You're seeing this exception because you're using `async`/`await` on ASP.NET 4.0, which is not supported. You need to ensure that you're targeting .NET 4.5 and that [you have set `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` in your web.config](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx).

Comment: I tried await everywhere but it did not work. I checked all of my project properties, they are all set to .NET 4.5 However, in one of my projects I have this line.   <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup> Could this be the problem ?

Comment: No, that's normal. Are you *absolutely sure* that the `httpRuntime` element has the correct `targetFramework`?

Comment: I had  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"> but I added  targetFramework="4.5" to <httpruntime> as well. When I reach return await client.GetStringAsync(url); while debugging , nothing happens and I see System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] on page.

Comment: Update all your NuGet packages. You're running a very old version of MVC.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to await on the call to `plane.GetSuggestions("ISTANBUL");`

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var plane = new Scanner();
    var model = await plane.GetSuggestions("ISTANBUL");

    return View(model);
}
```

When you're debugging the code, it likely is wokring as expected, since you are stepping through the code. Howver, once you let the code run naturally, since the call to `plane.GetSuggestions("ISTANBUL");` is not awaiting, and thus goes ahead and calls `return View(model);` before `plane.GetSuggestions("ISTANBUL");` has had a chance to finish.

I think that's why you're not getting the expected result.

Comment: I tried but when I do this, I get Object ref. not set to instance ... exception on return await client.GetStringAsync(url); I edited my question with exception details