# httpClient.postAsync - Fire-and-Forget - Async Confusion

Tags: vb.net, async-await, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I have a vb **console application** that acts a a relay to a desktop application - posting data to an online service.

Because posts are relatively large and frequent, my intention is to 'fire and forget'.  That is to say, I would like the console application to post data and never wait for a response (I control the online service and errors can be handled at the the other end).

`httpClient postAsync()` seemed like a simple solution, but I am confused by the terminology - despite having read various useful posts found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)

Ultimately, it seems that the way to achieve what I want to do is to use a `Sub` and not a `Function` as follows (this is called by `Sub Main()`):

```
Public Sub POSTRequest(ByVal url As String, ByVal data As String, ByVal format As String)

    Dim content_type As String = ""        

    Select Case format
        Case "xml"
            content_type = "application/xml"
        Case "json"
            content_type = "application/json"
        Case "form"
            content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    End Select        

    Try            
        Dim httpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
        Dim httpContent = New StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, content_type)
        httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent)
        Dim response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent).Result
        'I DON'T CARE ABOUT THE VALUE OF RESPONSE, SO NOTHING IS RETURNED...
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

First, this seems confusing and counter-intuitive.  Is not the point of `Async / Await` to *prevent* deadlock and to *allow* multiple tasks to run simultaneously?

Secondly, how would I wrap this `Sub` (presumably as a `Function`) so as to allow multiple http posts to occur simultaneously (or in very quick succession) and *only* return any errors (e.g. a response code <> 200) and only after *all* the posts have been made?

Comment: .Result will block. Just remove the second line of code where you call postasync and the function will return without waiting.

Comment: Thanks but removing `Dim response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent).Result` means that the http request never fires.  I want to fire and forget - so I want to fire but I don't want to wait for the result returned by `.Result` ...

Comment: The request does fire, it is just that the running thread is killed before it can do anything. For demonstration only, do a Thread.Sleep(1000) after `httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent)`. I don't know how you are monitoring the request, but you will be able to see it is indeed hit. You can still use `await` with simultaneous calls so you'll probably end up doing that in the end.

Comment: I will try this but I think Stephen Cleary has provided the answer I was after.  Thanks

Comment: yes, something tells me you can trust him on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ultimately, it seems that the way...

All asynchronous methods should be `Function` and return `Task` (or `Task (of T)`), unless they're implementing event handlers.

> Is not the point of Async / Await to...

You're not actually using `Async` or `Await` in the code you posted. `Result` is *not* intended for use with asynchronous tasks; use `Await` instead. Since you're writing a Console application, you'll eventually find that you do need to block once - in your `Main` method - to prevent the application from exiting. You can do this using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on your single top-level task.

> allow multiple http posts to occur simultaneously

Asynchronous concurrency is most easily done by saving the `Task` (e.g., in a `List (of Task)`) instead of using `Await` right away, and then later passing the collection of tasks to `Task.WhenAll` and `Await`ing that.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - so I really need a three-level solution with the 'executive' function at the bottom that returns the `List (of Task)`, a function that calls the executive function and awaits and handles its returned `List (of Task)` and at the top, `Sub Main()` which calls the middle layer function?  I will now go away and try that...

Comment: In a console app, I recommend having your `Sub Main()` just call `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, where `MainAsync` is an asynchronous `Function (Of Task)`. Within that `MainAsync` you can do things like build the list of tasks and pass that to `Task.WhenAll`.