# How to trigger (NOT avoid!) an HttpClient deadlock

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock, dotnet-httpclient

There are a number of questions on SO about how to *avoid* deadlocks in async code (for example, `HttpClient` methods) being called from sync code, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async). I'm aware of the various ways to avoid these deadlocks.

In contrast, I'd like to learn about strategies to *aggravate* or *trigger* these deadlocks in faulty code during testing.

Here's an example bit of bad code that recently caused problems for us:

```
public static string DeadlockingGet(Uri uri)
{
    using (var http = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = http.GetAsync(uri).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

It was being called from an ASP.NET app, and thus had a non-`null` value of `SynchronizationContext.Current`, which provided the fuel for a potential deadlock fire.

Aside from [blatantly misusing HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), this code deadlocked in one of our company's servers... but only sporadically.

### My attempt to repro deadlock

I work in QA, so I tried to repro the deadlock via a unit test that hits a local instance of Fiddler's listener port:

```
public class DeadlockTest
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase("http://localhost:8888")]
    public void GetTests(string uri)
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
        var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        var thread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        var result = DeadlockingGet(new Uri(uri));
        var thread2 = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    }
}
```

A couple things to note:

- By default, a unit test has a null `SynchronizationContext.Current`, [and so `.Result` captures the context of `TaskScheduler`, which is the thread pool context](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). Therefore I use `SetSynchronizationContext` to set it to a specific context, to more closely emulate what happens in an ASP.NET or UI context.
- I've configured Fiddler to wait a while (~1 minute) before responding back. I've heard from coworkers that this may help repro the deadlock (but I have no hard evidence this is the case).
- I've ran it with debugger to make sure that `context` is non-`null` and `thread == thread2`.

Unfortunately, I've had no luck triggering deadlocks with this unit test. It always finishes, no matter how long the delay in Fiddler is, unless the delay exceeds the 100-second default `Timeout` of `HttpClient` (in which case it just blows up with an exception).

Am I missing an ingredient to ignite a deadlock fire? I'd like to repro the deadlocks, just to be positive that our eventual fix actually works.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you think that setting *any* synchronization context might cause deadlock with async code - that is not true. It is dangerous to block on async code in asp.net and UI applications because they have special, single, main thread. In UI applications that is, well, main UI thread, in ASP.NET applications there are many such threads, but for given request there is one - request thread.

Synchronization contexts of ASP.NET and UI applications are special in that they basically send callbacks to that one special thread. So when:

1. you execute some code on this thread
2. from that code you execute some async `Task` and block on it's `Result`.
3. That `Task` has await statement.

Deadlock will occur. Why this happens? Because continuation of async method is `Post`ed to current synchronization context. Those special contexts we discuss above will send those continuations to the special main thread. You already execute code on this same thread and it is already blocked - hence deadlock.

So what are you doing wrong? First, `SynchronizationContext` is not special context we discussed above - it just posts continuations to thread pool thread. You need another one for tests. You can either use existing (like `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`), or create simple context which behaves the same (sample code, ONLY for demonstration purposes):

```
class QueueSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext {
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>> _queue = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>>(new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>>());
    public QueueSynchronizationContext() {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
                item.Item1(item.Item2);
            }
        }).Start();
    }        

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        _queue.Add(new Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>(d, state));
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) {
        // Send should be synchronous, so we should block here, but we won't bother
        // because for this question it does not matter
        _queue.Add(new Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>(d, state));
    }
}
```

All it does is puts all callbacks to single queue and executes them one by one on separate, single thread.

Simulating deadlock with this context is easy:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new QueueSynchronizationContext();
        ctx.Send((state) =>
        {
            // first, execute code on this context
            // so imagine you are in ASP.NET request thread,
            // or in WPF UI thread now                
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ctx);
            Deadlock(new Uri("http://google.com"));   
            Console.WriteLine("No deadlock if got here");
        }, null);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void NoDeadlock(Uri uri) {
        DeadlockingGet(uri).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
        });
    }

    public static string Deadlock(Uri uri)
    {
        // we are on "main" thread, doing blocking operation
        return DeadlockingGet(uri).Result;
    }

    public static async Task<string> DeadlockingGet(Uri uri) {
        using (var http = new HttpClient()) {
            // await in async method
            var response = await http.GetAsync(uri);
            // this is continuation of async method
            // it will be posted to our context (you can see in debugger), and will deadlock
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that it's not the existence of a `SynchronizationContext` that causes the deadlock, but rather the way the context implements its `Post/Send` methods used to resume execution when a callback occurs. That helps! The one thing I still don't understand in your code is why replacing `Deadlock` with my original synchronous definition of `DeadlockingGet` doesn't seem to trigger deadlocks. Any ideas why that doesn't deadlock, but your example does?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus DeadlockingGet does not use async\await anywhere, nor it is used by HttpClient methods internally (both GetAsync and ReadAsStringAsync use regular task completion sources and Task.ContinueWith internally) - so it should not deadlock. How do you know exactly this code block deadlocked in your case?

Comment: We profiled one of the operations when it froze, see http://imgur.com/a/LnMln for profile results (I've censored corporate namespaces in red). The 1st picture shows the stack containing the deadlocking method, which is `HttpClientWrapper.Post` (implementation is identical to my `DeadlockingGet` except it uses `PostAsync`), and you can see 50% is spend on `Wait()`. The 2nd picture shows the other 50% is spent on `System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback`. AFAIK these are the hallmarks of a profiled deadlock.

Comment: The exact implementation of `HttpClientWrapper.Post` is `public string Post(Uri uri, string dataToPost, string mediaType)
{
 using (var http = new HttpClient())
 {
  var response = http.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(dataToPost, Encoding.Default, mediaType)).Result;
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 }
}
`, which still _shouldn't_ deadlock. I'm beginning to wonder if the deadlock is being caused by something else in the call stack.

Comment: As I understand, this deadlock does not happen always, just from time to time? Can you also post how asp.net method which executes that looks like (top level controller method). Is it async?

Answer (score 4):

You have not been able to reproduce the issue because `SynchronizationContext` itself does not mimic the context installed by ASP.NET. The base `SynchronizationContext` does no locking or synchronization, but the ASP.NET context does: Because `HttpContext.Current` is not thread-safe nor is it stored in the `LogicalCallContext` to be passed between threads, the `AspNetSynchronizationContext` does a bit of work to a. restore `HttpContext.Current` when resuming a task and b. lock to ensure that only one task is running for a given context.

A similar problem exists with MVC: http://btburnett.com/2016/04/testing-an-sdk-for-asyncawait-synchronizationcontext-deadlocks.html

The approach given there is to test your code with a context which ensures that `Send` or `Post` is never called on the context. If it is, this is an indication of the deadlocking behavior. To resolve, either make the method tree `async` all the way up or use `ConfigureAwait(false)` somewhere, which essentially detaches the task completion from the sync context. For more information, this article details [when you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)