# Async method to make an http call using HttpClient never comes back

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have the following piece of code in a domain service:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.GetAsync("http://somewebsite.com").Result;
```

Which works fine, I can place a break point on followed lines and they do hit and all is good. However, I have the same line of code in a nuget package installed in this very same project. There there's the exact same http call:

```
public class Client : Base
{
    public Task<List<Stuff>> GetAsync()
    {
        return SendMessageAsync(HttpMethod.Get, "http://getstuff.com")
            .ContinueWith(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StuffView>>(x.Result.Content.ReasAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
}
public class Base
{
    HttpClient client:

    public Base(HttpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client:
    }
    protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetMessageAsync(BttpMethod method, string url)
    {
        var request = CreateRequestAsync(method, url);
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request); //line 1
        return response; // Line 2
    }
    protected HttpRequestMessage CreateRequestAsync(HttpMethod method, string url) 
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
        request.SetBearerToken(myAccessTokenProvider);
        return request;
    }
}
```

This is how my domain service is using the nuget package code:

```
var client = factory.Create();
client.GetAsync().Result;
```

Debugging this code shows that inside Base class line 1 is hit but line 2 never does. Searching on internet it seems like a thread deadlock issue. So my question is, assuming it's a deadlock, why the heck the first http call in domain service works but not the second one that uses the nuget package code?!

HttpClient deadlock issue: 
[HttpClient.GetAsync(...) never returns when using await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)

Comment: Never use `.*Async().Result`.

Comment: @SLaks what to use then? GetAwaiter().GetResults() has the same issue, never comes back. No errors to be found anywhere.

Comment: @Hani, you must `await` async calls to avoid deadlocks and to allow Asp.Net to operate as it was designed.

Comment: That's great, why does the first example works then?

Comment: @Hani `x.Result.Content.ReasAsStringAsync().Result` is the cause of the problem. The first `.Result` is allowed as its task has already completed from the previous call. the second `.Result` is mixing async and blocking call. hence the deadlock. Try to avoid mixing async and blocking calls. it is either one or the other all the way through.

Comment: @Nkosi just removed the serialization and return type changed to HttResponseMessage and still the same issue. The way I see it, it seems that we don't know exactly in fine details how asp.net behaves in the first example?

Comment: The first example does not lock because the synchronization context is not waiting on two things. But it is still a mean thing to do to Asp.Net's thread model. Did you read the links Stephen Cleary listed in his answer to the question you linked to?

Comment: @Crowcoder as I mentioned removing that piece of code didn't change anything, so when you say first example works because it's not waiting for two things, then second example should start working after modifying it to wait for one thing. But it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example works because either the Task is in the `.Completed == true` state before you call `.Result` on it or that line of code has `SyncronisationContext.Current == null`.

If the task is not in the completed state calling `.Result` or `.Wait()` on a task can result in a deadlock if `SyncronisationContext.Current != null` at the point you called `.Result` or `.Wait()`. The best thing to do is mark the entire call stack as `async` and start returning `Task` instead of `void` and `Task<T>` where you return `T` then calling `await` on all places you used `.Result` or `.Wait()`.

If you are not willing to make those code changes you must switch to using non async methods, this will requite switching from `HttpClient` to `WebClient` and using it's non async method calls to do your requests.

Comment: Thanks Scott, any idea why the first task would complete so fast but the second one doesn't while they call the same web resource? here I'm assuming this is a timing issue that causes one task to be completed since there is no manual intervention to do that or mark SynchronizationContext as null.

Comment: If the work is being done on a background thread also sets it null. Doing work in a `.ContinueWith` can also cause it.

Comment: What exactly sets the SynchronizationContext and how can I change that behavior, if at all?

Comment: The Framework you are using ex: Winforms, WPF, or ASP.NET sets it on the "UI Thread". See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) for more info on how it works

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `.Result`. With `.Result`, the I/O is started (asynchronously) where the calling thread (synchronously) blocks waiting for it to complete.

Just use `await`.

```
var stuff = await client.GetAsync();
```

Comment: Sure, buy why is the first example work fine?! That's doing a .Result too.

Comment: @Hani Nkosi's comment above. Its spot on.