# How do I get Async/Await working in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Consider this non-async method called `Forward` which works exactly as expected when called (in C#) with `Forward(forwardUrl, content);`

```
    private ActionResult Forward(string forwardUrl, FormUrlEncodedContent content)
    {
        // NOTE - httpClient is a static HttpClient instance

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        switch (Request.RequestType.ToUpperInvariant())
        {
            case "GET":
                response = httpClient.GetAsync(forwardUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                break;
            case "POST":
                response = httpClient.PostAsync(forwardUrl, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to forward Request method {Request.RequestType}.");
        }

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return Content(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(), response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
```

That one works fine, but repeatedly calls `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which essentially blocks and makes it syncronous.

Now I have the following async method called `ForwardAsync` and here I call it with exactly the same arguments, but with the calling pattern of `ForwardAsync(forwardUrl, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

```
    private async Task<ActionResult> ForwardAsync(string forwardUrl, FormUrlEncodedContent content)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        switch (Request.RequestType.ToUpperInvariant())
        {
            case "GET":
                response = await httpClient.GetAsync(forwardUrl);
                break;
            case "POST":
                response = await httpClient.PostAsync(forwardUrl, content);
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to forward Request method {Request.RequestType}.");
        }

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return Content(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
        }

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
```

This one simply hangs.  In my test case I am going down the `POST` branch (in both scenarios) but the code never returns from `await httpClient.PostAsync(forwardUrl, content)`.  I am able to confirm that the request is posted, and the code does run on the forwarded URL, and responds, but the awaited method invocation simply doesn't return.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the code that calls into `ForwardAsync`

Comment: It is in the description - `return ForwardAsync(forwardUrl, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: Don't block on `async` methods, period. However, if you really really need to do it (and there is rarely a case you ever need to do this in a normal situation), sacrifice a thread pool thread and offload it, with task run then block that.

Comment: You may want to [edit] title of the post as it does not sound like you actually want to properly use async/await in controller, but rather correctly call async methods from synchronous methods (which really not a good idea, but not related to your question)

Comment: Please clarify do you call your controller endpoint with `ForwardAsync(forwardUrl, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`(within your test) or you do real HTTP call with `HttpClient`?

Comment: Also are you sure your endpoint accepts both GET and POST verbs?

Comment: HttpClient is for asynchronous use. If you want to synchronously download a string, use `WebClient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That one works fine, but repeatedly calls GetAwaiter().GetResult() which essentially blocks and makes it syncronous.
>
> Now I have the following async method called ForwardAsync and here I call it with exactly the same arguments, but with the calling pattern of ForwardAsync(forwardUrl, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

The new method also blocks and is synchronous. I'm not sure what value you're getting by making this change.

In addition, [by blocking on asynchronous code, the new code is susceptible to deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

I recommend either:

- Keeping the existing code as-is.
- Making the new code properly asynchronous. Which means calling it with `await` and not using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Don't use `Task.Run` on ASP.NET. In that environment, the thread pool belongs to ASP.NET, and regularly using `Task.Run` will throw off the thread pool heuristics.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary.  I've gone ahead to mark this "The Answer", and yet there remains a paradox.  I am working with an old code base.  I am adding new functionality.  MSDN strongly suggests not using old WebRequest syncronous code when developing new functionality.  Also I need async/await anyway because I am using some newer SDKs that require it.  So unless I can convince the older-code project management team to upgrade throughout (painful) I am stuck, in an (older) ASP.NET context, using either `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` or `Task.Run().Result`.

Comment: @StephanG: You may find my [Brownfield Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) article helpful. My answers (and blog posts) encourage the ideal solutions, but in the Real World sometimes things get messy. In your case, it sounds like keeping the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` calls throughout may be the best solution. I would be sure to provide an asynchronous API as well (using the Boolean Argument Hack from the article) so that your consumers can adopt `async` when they're ready.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary.  Nice article.

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer - in this scenario use:

`return Task.Run(() => ForwardAsync(forwardUrl, content)).Result;`

and do NOT use the GetAwaiter().GetResult() pattern.

I found this SO question helpful, and it has the longer and correct answer:  [HttpClient.GetAsync(...) never returns when using await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)

Many thanks to all who commented on the initial question with clarifying insights.

Comment: Don't use `Task.Run` on web applications. It does more harm than good.