# async task<T> not returning

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on converting my code to async and I'm stumped with this problem. My CallRestAPI is not returning. I can debug every line of code, even down to the return e; but it then goes to the last bracket and then hangs. for code completeness, I moved the httpclient into this method so a complete code example.

from the UI Thread, I call - [Dim result = ExecuteDSSTP(params...)].

The code does not return from CallRestAPI when serializing. It seems to run all the way through, but doesn't return.

```
 public DataSet ExecuteDSSTP(string asStoredProcedure, params object[] aoParams)
    {
        return ExecuteDSSTPAsync(asStoredProcedure, aoParams).Result;
    }

public async Task<DataSet> ExecuteDSSTPAsync(string asStoredProcedure, params object[] aoParams)
    {

        dbUtilityResponse retVal = new dbUtilityResponse();
            
       
        retVal = await CallRestAPI<dbUtilityResponse>("ExecuteSTP", new DbUtilityRequest() {Params....});
      

        return retVal.ResultDataSet;
    }


   private static async Task<T> CallRestAPI<T>(string method, object body)
    {

            var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(SerializeBson(body));
            byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

            var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            var response2 = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://myurl/" + method, byteArrayContent).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

            var ms = new MemoryStream(await response2.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
            using (var reader = new BsonDataReader(ms))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                var e = serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
                return e;
            }
       
    }
```

Comment: just so you know. The method will in effect return at the first `await`. While the `return e` will set the returned task as completed. So what does the caller code looks like? How is the returned task handled?

Comment: Are you using async methods all the way up the chain?

Comment: @john no, it's called from a sync UI method. I'll post more code!

Comment: This looks like a deadlock. Why are you not calling: `var dataset = await ExecuteDSSTPAsync(//...` from your UI thread?

Comment: The UI thread in this app hasn't been converted to async yet.

Comment: I believe you also need to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside your `ExecuteDSSTPAsync`. Since it's not used there it configures that call to resume on the UI thread, but it can't because the `UI` thread is busy waiting on the `.Result`. In general this is a very bad setup (it's not good to block the UI thread). Mistakes like this are prone to occur with a setup like this.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely this is due to a deadlock

```
ExecuteDSSTPAsync(asStoredProcedure, aoParams).Result
```

`.Result` will stop the current (i.e. UI) thread from executing until the task is completed. However, the task cannot complete until it has run the code after `_httpClient.PostAsync`, and it needs to do this on the same context as the caller, i.e. the UI thread. But it cannot do this, since the UI thread is stopped at `.Result`.

So, classic deadlock. Because of this it is recommended to avoid `.Result` since it so easily results in deadlocks like this.

You should instead use `await` all the way to the UI layer. At the UI layer you should also make sure to call await in a try/catch statement to ensure you catch any exception and can present to the user or otherwise deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

@Knoop's comment led me to the right answer. Working code is below! It appears I need to use ConfigureAwait(False)

I also used this answer [See answer best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)

```
  public DataRowCollection ExecuteSTPCred(DBConnection aConnection, string dbcCredentials, string asStoredProcedure, params object[] aoParams)
    {
        return ExecuteSTPCredAsync(aConnection, dbcCredentials, asStoredProcedure, aoParams).Result;
    }


  public async Task<DataRowCollection> ExecuteSTPCredAsync(DBConnection aConnection, string dbcCredentials, string asStoredProcedure, params object[] aoParams)
    {

        dbUtilityResponse retVal = new dbUtilityResponse();
        
            retVal = await CallRestAPI<dbUtilityResponse>("ExecuteSTP", new DbUtilityRequest()
            {
                params...
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return retVal.ResultDataSet.Tables[0].Rows;
    }


  private static async Task<T> CallRestAPI<T>(string method, object body)
    {

        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(SerializeBson(body));
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

        var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        var response2 = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://MyUrl/" + method, byteArrayContent).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        var ms = new MemoryStream(await response2.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
        using (var reader = new BsonDataReader(ms))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);

        }

    }
```