# Get open extensions using Graph API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am building a ASP.NET Core website, where the user signs in, and is able to save things like the theme of the page, which then triggers some js code:

```
var data = {
    userName: userName,
    key: "theme",
    value: localStorage.getItem("theme")
}

var pendingRequest;

if (pendingRequest) {
    pendingRequest.abort()
    pendingRequest = null;
}

pendingRequest = $.post('/Account/setExtension', data, function (data) {
    pendingRequest = null;
    $('#settingsModal').modal('hide');
});
```

which calls the controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public void setExtension(string userName, string key, string value)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> addData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {key, value }
        };
        GraphHelper.updateExtension(userName, "com.user.roamingSettings", addData).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

which calls the checks if the extension exists, and then decides to create it, or update the existing extension:

```
        public static async Task<bool> extensionExistsAsync(string userName, string extensionName)
    {
        try
        {
            var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();

            // if extension doesnt exist
            bool extensionFound = false;
            var extensions = await graphClient.Users[userName].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();

            foreach (var extension in extensions)
            {
                if (extension.Id == extensionName)
                {
                    extensionFound = true;
                }
            }
            return extensionFound;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the code just stops running on this line:

```
var extensions = await graphClient.Users[userName].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();
```

It doesn't throw or anything. Stepping through it line by line, it returns all the way to the assignment, and the output window is empty when it stops. Why is this? How can I get an extension by name, or get all extensions to see which ones exist, either by graph api, or calls?

Comment: Please share the code of `GetAuthenticatedClient()`.

Comment: Have you tested in [graph explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) with the call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/extensions`?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Yes, I am able to make calls both with graph explorer and postman just fine, but doing it the way above, it just stops.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: This ended up solving it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you use the below call

```
var extensions = await graphClient.Users[userName].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();
```

you will be getting UserExtensionsCollectionPage object which gives the list of extensions of a user.

This page doesn't have Id property, the extension objects that are present in this UserExtensionsCollectionPage object have it. So use the below code to print the id and type of the Extensions.

```
var extensions = await graphClient.Users["a1ee289f-4cab-4fc3-885f-d4cbefb48895"].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();
foreach(var data in extensions.CurrentPage)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Id: " + data.Id + "Type: " + data.ODataType );
}
```

This will give you the data as below.

[image]

Comment: This still just stops running at the line var extensions ...

Comment: Please keep a break point in visual studio and see what you can catch and also remove the foreach for now as we are testing it and print value in extensions variable.