# Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) error when calling Web API inside a Loop

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a scenario where I'm calling a Web API and doing a computation based on the results in the `data` section of the JSON. However, the response of API is paginated, like so:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 5,
  "total": 500,
  "total_pages": 100,
  "data": [
    {
      "competition": "UEFA Champions League",
      "year": 2011,
      "round": "GroupH",
      "team1": "Barcelona",
      "team2": "AC Milan",
      "team1goals": "2",
      "team2goals": "2"
    },
    {
      "competition": "UEFA Champions League",
      "year": 2011,
      "round": "GroupG",
      "team1": "APOEL Nikosia",
      "team2": "Zenit St. Petersburg",
      "team1goals": "2",
      "team2goals": "1"
    },
    {
      "competition": "UEFA Champions League",
      "year": 2011,
      "round": "GroupF",
      "team1": "Borussia Dortmund",
      "team2": "Arsenal",
      "team1goals": "1",
      "team2goals": "1"
    }
}
```

For me to get to the next page to get more data, I have to pass the `page` number in the QueryString like so:

```
https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=2011&page=2
```

So I have put this in a for loop to iterate thru those 100 pages to compute the result. And as I am iterating thru the 100 pages, I get an execution Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) error before the code could get to the 7th page in the loop. Here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        int year = 2011;
        var result = Result.getNumDraws(year);
        Console.WriteLine("Match drawn = " + result);
    }
}

class Result
{   
        public static int getNumDraws(int year)
    {
        var totalDrawn = 0;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var baseURL = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=" + year.ToString();
        var current = client.GetAsync(baseURL).Result;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(current.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    
        for (int i = 1; i <= result.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("iterating thru pages = " + i);
            var response =  GetMatchInfo(year, i);

            foreach (var match in response.data)
            {
                if (match.team1goals == match.team2goals)
                    totalDrawn++;
            }
        }

        return totalDrawn;
    }

    public static ApiData GetMatchInfo(int year, int page)
    {
        var url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=" + year.ToString() + "&page=" + page;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            
            var currentData = client.GetAsync(url).Result;          
            var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiData>(currentData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            return response;        
        }
    }
}

public class ApiResponse
{
    public string Page { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total_pages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
}

public class ApiData
{
    public List<Goal> data { get; set; }
}

public class Goal
{
    public int team1goals { get; set; }

    public int team2goals { get; set; }
}
```

Could you please guide me on what tweak or update I need to make in my code to address the Execution Time Limit error?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you getting the time limit exceeded error - as a return value to GetAsync or an exception? May be the API endpoint is throttling too many calls within short period of time.

Comment: and why are you not using *await* GetAsync()... ? see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async)

Comment: And you should not instantiate this many `HttpClient` objects, you should declare one as static at application level and reuse it.

Comment: I believe the API itself is not throttling, I am submitting this code in an online portal that has a maximum execution time of about 5 seconds. The code executes fine for the first couple of seconds and errors out saying the execution time limit was exceeded.

Comment: You need to add await , and have only 1 instance of HttpClient as I mentioned above. Even otherwise, calling that HTTP GET 100 times is going to take time and will not finish within 5 seconds. Please get to know more about what that online portal's restrictions are, looks like contest , so it is not going to be simple answer as you implemented.

Comment: You may also check whether you can instruct the API to return more items within one page (aka _page size_)

Comment: thank mu88 for the comment, this is an API from HackerRank app and can't really update API to return all or more items in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have now updated the code to include `async` and `await` and have defined a single static `HttpClient` object as shown here:

```
public class Program {

    public static void Main () {        
        int year = 2011;
        var result = Result.getNumDraws (year);
        Console.WriteLine ("Match drawn = " + result);
    }
}

class Result {
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();

    public static async Task<int> getNumDraws (int year) {
        var totalDrawn = 0;
        
        var baseURL = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=" + year.ToString ();

        var current = await client.GetAsync (baseURL);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse> (current.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result);

        for (int i = 1; i <= result.TotalPages; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine ("iterating thru pages = " + i);
            var response = GetMatchInfo (year, i);
            foreach (var match in response.Result.data) {
                if (match.team1goals == match.team2goals)
                    totalDrawn++;
            }
        }

        return totalDrawn;
    }

    public static async Task<ApiData> GetMatchInfo (int year, int page) {
        var url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=" + year.ToString () + "&page=" + page;

        var currentData = await client.GetAsync (url);

        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiData> (currentData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result);
        return response;

    }
}

public class ApiResponse {
    public string Page { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty ("total_pages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
}

public class ApiData {
    public List<Goal> data { get; set; }
}

public class Goal {
    public int team1goals { get; set; }

    public int team2goals { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute the code in my console app and set a breakpoint, I see this information in the  `result` variable:
[image]

I am expecting the `result` variable to hold the total computed value but it shows some `Task`-related information because the calls are still being made to fetch the data from the Web API? What do we do here to get the total computed value in the `result` variable?

Comment: hi Anand, I have posted the updated code here, please let me know if there's anything I need to update here to get  the Web API computed details in the `result` variable of the Main method.