# HttpClient.PostAsync() method is hanging forever in C# xUnt test

Tags: c#, mstest, xunit, dotnet-httpclient, visual-studio-test-runner

I have 600 functional xUnit tests and each of the test is calling a `httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl)` and `httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, data)` methods in the middle of the test which will call some external APIs.

When I execute each test sequentially all working fine. Also even when I run 5 - 6 test cases parallelly then also everything works fine.

My problem is, when I start all 600 test cases from the top (which will start around 50 out 600 test cases parallelly), all the tests are hanging where it sends the `httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, data)` method.

The same issue happened at the point where it executes the `httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl)` method. But after I change it as `httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false)` it fix the issue.

But when I change the `httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, data)` to `httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, data).ConfigureAwait(false)` issue is still the same.

Can someone explain why this happens and what should I do to fix this issue.

Comment: How HttpClient is injected in actual code? Is HttpClient is static instance or every flow creates a new instance of HttpClient?

Comment: @user1672994, each test case creates its own HttpClient instance. its not a static instance.

Comment: Is there a chance the service simply won't respond to 600 requests at once? (e.g. because of DoS protection, or rate limiting, or because it can't handle it performance-wise)

Comment: @JohnWu, No its not sending any responses nor throwing any exceptions. I've set few console logs to check the execution path. After it hits the httpClient.PostAsync() method, it just hangs there forever.

Comment: do you await this tasks?

Comment: It seems the issue is with you using 500 httpclient instances. Can't you create one instance and let that handle all your test cases?

Comment: `HttpClient` is thread-safe, it makes sense to inject it in order to cut down on the number of sockets

Comment: @d00lar, Yes I await the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I change the `httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, data)` method as below, it fix the issue. I'm not sure what the difference between two methods.

Previous way

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, data);
```

I modified above as below and it fixed the issue.

```
var task = httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, data);
var response = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Also I found some similar problem that has been discussed in below post. If someone facing similar issue, please follow below post as it contains some more useful tips and reasons.
[HttpClient.GetAsync(...) never returns when using await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async/10351400#10351400)

Comment: I have no idea why, but this fixed my problem :)